# Нужно осуществить поиск в веб-клиенте базы данных

Tags: c#, mysql

Есть веб-клиент базы данных
Не могу сделать так, чтобы работал Search

```
    <from a asp-action="Index" method="get">
<div class="from-group">
    <label for="SearchString"> Введите слово для поиска </label>
    <input type="text" class="from-group" name="SearchString"
           value="@ViewData["CurrentFilter"] "/>
    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn-primary" />
</div>
```

Еще есть вот такое

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string SearchString)
    {
        //return View(await _context.Incident.ToListAsync());
        ViewData["CurrentFilter"] = SearchString;
        var incident = from b in _context.Incident
                       select b;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SearchString))
        {
            incident = incident.Where(b => b.Context_Incident.Contains(SearchString));

        }
        return View( incident);
    }
```

Comment: И.... От нас вы что хотите? Я вон вижу, что какой-то поиск вы делаете, это вы просите и от нас, ок, задача решена я так понимаю? К чему тогда вопрос?